# preg_match - replace urls NOT surrounded by quotes

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need to add links to urls in some content which are not already linked. This content comes from many places inside Joomla and sometimes it is html and sometimes it is text. I need a one liner regular expression which does this.

consider the content:

```
some text then url: <a href="http://j25.localhost/something">Link</a> and some
other text<br />url:http://j25.localhost/something2 and some other text...
```

the regular expression I have is this:

```
$content = preg_replace('@(?:[^"])(https?://?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $content);
```

and it nearly works (it skips the first one and matches the second) but on the second one it includes the character ":" right before the "http...." and after replacement my ":" is gone resulting in: "`<br />url<a ...`" instead of "`<br />url:<a ...`"

what to do?

Comment: How about: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j25.localhost/site.js"></script>` ?

Comment: there should not be any of that but the first group in the regex should exclude it anyways

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Your problem isn't that you want to replace URLs not surrounded by quotes.  Your problem is that you want to replace URLs that are not in <A> tags.  Parse the HTML using an HTML parser, replace URLs that are found in plain text, not in tags, and then reassemble the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code with this:

```
$content = preg_replace(
  '@(^|[^"])(https?://?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@i',
  '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>', $content);
```

This will capture and the character just before `http://` and place it in the output text.

Though I must caution you that regex is not very reliable way of parsing HTML text.